# MongoDB pagination with $unwind and sort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume I have a very large items MongoDB database where each item has an array of embedded documents `variants`.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  item: "item1",
  variants: [
    { type: "type1" },
    { type: "type2" }
  ]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  item: "item2",
  variants: [
    { type: "type1" },
    { type: "type3" }
  ]
}
...
```

My goal is to generate a flattened paginated table and being able to sort each column.

Paginated table sorted by variant type:

```
 _id ↕ | item ↕ | type ↕  
-------+--------+--------
 1     | item1  | type1
 2     | item2  | type1   
 1     | item1  | type2
 2     | item2  | type3
...

< (1),2,3,4,5 ... 54323 >
```

My approach is to get a subset for each pagination page using the MonogoDB aggregation pipeline

```
db.items.aggregate([
  $unwind: {
    path: '$variants.type',
    includeArrayIndex: 'variant_index'
  },
  $sort: {
    'variants.type': 1
  }, {
    $skip: 0
  }, {
    $limit: 50
  }
])
```

Unfortunately for large datasets this is a very expensive sort operation and can even lead in my concrete implementation to a `Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes` error.

My question is if it's possible to optimise this for good performance without moving the variants data in a separate collection (which is not possible). I thought about using "Multikey Indexes" but I can't figure out how they could be used here.

Comment: Create a multi key index on  the `variants.type` field. `db.collection.createIndex( { "variants.type": 1 } )`

Comment: if I understand the documentation correctly a $sort after $unwind can not take advantage of Multikey Indexes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-operator-and-performance

Comment: oops!!! Yes you are right. You need to find some different way.